# Skype Bots - Visual Cards or HTML responses

Tags: bots, skype, skypedeveloper

I've started looking into developing [Skype Bots](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots) and I'm a bit confused on how my bot can respond with something other than plain text. I watched a video on [How to build a bot for Skype](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/T611) from the Build 2016 conference and they mentioned something about Visual Cards. Basically a visual card seems to be a clickable image with text and/or a carousel of clickable images. Anyways... I basically want to send the user something nice and pretty that they can click to obtain more information. Thank you for any direction you can give.

Comment: Please detail what you have already tried. [so] is a resource for helping people solve their programming problems, as opposed to a free code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supported capabilities in Skype are shown at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/docs. These do not currently include rich cards but hopefully something that isn't too far away.